# How to save and create files in internal device storage flutter

Tags: flutter, file

How can I save and create files in internal device storage in flutter? When I create file with getExternalStorageDirectory(), the file hasn't appeared in internal storage.

```
          String fileExtension = name!.split('.').last;
          String fileName =
              name!.replaceAll('.${fileExtension}', '');

          String? localPath = await _findLocalPath();

          String completePath = '${localPath}/${fileName}.${fileExtension}';

          logger.e(completePath);
          io.File file = io.File(completePath);
          await file.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
          file.create();
```

```
Future<String?> _findLocalPath() async {
    String? externalStorageDirPath;
    if (io.Platform.isAndroid) {
      final io.Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      externalStorageDirPath = directory!.path;
    } else if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
      externalStorageDirPath =
          (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).absolute.path;
    }
    final io.Directory savedDir = io.Directory(externalStorageDirPath!);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    logger.e(hasExisted);
    if (!hasExisted) {
      logger.e('Create Folder');
      savedDir.create();
    }
    return externalStorageDirPath;
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the top block of code with this:

```
      String fileExtension = name!.split('.').last;
      String fileName =
          name!.replaceAll('.${fileExtension}', '');

      String? localPath = await _findLocalPath();

      String completePath = '${localPath}/${fileName}.${fileExtension}';

      logger.e(completePath);
      io.File file = io.File(completePath);
      //await file.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
      //file.create();
      var output = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);

      await for (final data in dataStore) {
        output.add(data);
      }

      await output.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the file isn't still appear in internal storage.

Comment: In that case, make sure that the app has the required permissions to store data in external storage, From the block of code you provided, it does not. If you want to store information into the application's directory where permission is required, refer to this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files